# UI lags when setImage() to ImageView Android

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I have scrollView with LinearLayout inside.
In this layout I add ImageView (by code) and start download bitmap from web (asyncTask).
In postExecute I do imageView.setImageBitmap(result); result = bitmap from web.

And when I scroll my scrollView I see lags when bitmap adding to imageView. Any ideas how to remove this lags?

**EDITED**

There is no lags when I comment:

```
//imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine exactly where your lag comes from.

Comment: I'm noticing something similar. Did you ever determine exactly what the source of this problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the ImageView sizes from the start? if not and your ImageView is set to WRAP_CONTENT it will cause relayout when you set an image and it will cause lag if you are scrolling.

Comment: Hi Alex, may I ask what is the workaround for this? I set the width and height in my layout xml. But on some devices background.setImageView will cause serious lag. What parameters should I set?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). It will do all the lazy loading will need for you. All you need to do is pass it the imageview and the url. It'll even do caching for you (if you want) so that it won't redownload the same image over and over again.